# Orleans: Right way to separate Grain types within single cluster

Tags: orleans

I have several *Grain* types in my *Orleans* project. Lets say *Grains* are **A,B,C,D,E**.
I have single *Silo* executable which i run on 2 machines (clustering via *AdoNet*). 
So, they communicate and ping each other and I able to consume grains through client.

Now I want to run *Silo* executables on several machines on a network in such way that grains of types **A,B,C** will be hosted on machine **1** while **D** and **E** are hosted on machine **2**. 
Ideally, within single executable (project) using runtime-configuration.

I tried, as written on article below, to just skip implementation types referencing of grains **D** and **E**, leaving only interfaces, but always get Silo fault with error

```
Cannot find an implementation class for grain interface: ... Make sure the grain assembly was correctly deployed and loaded in the silo.
```

Also the note is that grain **A** consumes grains **D** and **E**, So, when activating grain **A**, always getting silo fault.

I have read this article from top to bottom and backwards but still cannot understand how to distinguish what grain types should be run on particular silo instance.

https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/clusters_and_clients/heterogeneous_silos.html

Comment: is there a particular architectural consideration that you `need` to run heterogeneous silos? Cause you just introducing pain (unless you like pain).

Comment: there are some network-consuming grains, some memory-consuming grains and some cpu-consuming grains. my cloud provider has separate HW configurations narrowed on cpu-optimization, memory-optimization etc. also, some cpu-consuming hard-loaded grains on active phase eat all the resources and slow down avg performance of other more lightweight, but more response-critical grains. 
for example, i use ffmpeg in one grain, which is not time critical, but when it starts it eat all cpu, so i want to move that grain type to separate machine not to interfere with other more responsive grains.

Comment: sounds like your looking for a placementstrategy

Comment: BozoJoe, yes, thank you! Looks like that placementstrategy is the right direction.